# I need help getting Regex expression correct 2

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a quick guru help :) Got the url
http://www.blahblah.com/?ssct=654654654654654#games/park
I need to apply the regex to remove ?ssct=654654654654654 from the url.
I have replace(/\?.*#/, '') this in place, but it gets rid of # sign which I need. Thank you for help.

Comment: Just put the missing # back after you get done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest variation that works is

```
/\?[^#]*/
```

which matches a literal `'?'` character followed by any number of characters other than `'#'`.

```
"http://www.blahblah.com/?ssct=654654654654654#games/park".replace(/\?[^#]*/, '')

===

"http://www.blahblah.com/#games/park"
```

That correctly handles the case where the URI reference is always hierarchical (`http` vs `mailto` which is "opaque") and has a query component.

---

## Caveat

There's ways to make mistakes with simple regular expressions though.  For example, this approach has problems with

```
"http://www.blahblah.com/#games/park?duck"
```

where the first `?` appears inside the fragment instead of in the query.

To be bulletproof, you really need to properly parse the URI.  [RFC 3986 Appendix B](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) contains:

> The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a well-formed URI reference into its components.

So to be correct for all hierarchical URIs, you would need to do something like

```
var myUrl = "http://www.blahblah.com/?ssct=654654654654654#games/park";
myUrl.replace(/^(([^:/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/, "$1$3$5$8")
```

This is probably over-kill for a one-off, but another alternative is to use a JS library that provides proper URI handling primitives like [Closure's Uri module](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_Uri.html)

```
var urlWithoutQuery =
   new goog.Uri("http://www.blahblah.com/?ssct=654654654654654#games/park")
   .setQuery('')
   .toString()
```

Comment: +1 for the Caveat. Otherwise, this answer is as average as any other.

Comment: @nhahtdh, what do you look for in an above-average answer?

Comment: Email, URI, HTML ... these are very complex if we look at the specs.  While it is OK to make assumption - since people normally don't walk on the border, it is also necessary to explicitly mention the assumption that we are making.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Would it pass muster if I prefixed this with "Assuming your URI reference is always hierarchical and always has a query component, ..."?

Comment: The caveat already serves as a good warning already, but it doesn't hurt to add. Well, it's my own opinion anyway...

Comment: @nhahtdh, please see my edits and don't apologize for having opinions.  Putting opinions into words helps you separate the good from the bad and lets others benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Zero-width positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
replace(/\?.*(?=#)/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just replace it with '#' instead of an empty string?
`replace(/\?.*#/, '#')`

Answer (score -1):

Regex is not the most ideal solution.  In a valid URI format there will be only one "?" character.  So the best solution would be:

```
var a = location.href;
a = a.substring(0, a.indexOf("?"));
```

Comment: Section 3.5 of RFC 3986 says "`fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )`", so a valid URI reference can contain any number of `'?'`s.